# Filter in the Single Shot Detector

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, computer-vision, object-detection

Let's say I want to implement a single shot detector. When I get a feature mal as an input, I will use a 3x3 filter for prediction for each cell.
Let's say we have 5 classes with 6 ancors, I would have to create (5+4)*6(anchors) filters. That would be an output of 54 feature maps for prediction.

When I use them as input for the next layer and have a conv2d with 54 input and 54 output channels isn't that against the single shot detector architecture. Don't I have to use one feature maps again? Because in the end I should use 5 or six feature maps.
But what happens to the convolutional layer with the 54 outputs? When I don't put there outputs into another layer they won't get updated during back propagation

Comment: Can you please put your **specific question** in the title?